# Atlas controller ignores limits from URDF

Tags: control, drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the DRCSim 2.0, I have noticed that when sending position commands (to say for example the `neck_ay` joint), that the velocities reported by `/atlas/joint_states` are much higher than the velocity_limits defined in the URDF.

Can we expect this to be fixed for the VRC, or should we continue to assume that we can see velocity and/or effort values that exceed the URDF limits?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1333/atlas-controller-ignores-limits-from-urdf./) by [pbeeson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/126/pbeeson/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/126/pbeeson/) on 2013-02-11**:
I've noticed that because there is no limit checking going on, if you are tuning the PID controller, and choose a bad value for a PID gain, you can easily cause Gazebo to crash (presumably because the effort it commands is too high or low).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For effort limit, there is [a pull request in gazebo](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/289/use-effort-limit-set-in-sdf/diff).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/126/pbeeson/) on 2013-02-14**:
This pull  request works so much better than before, as tuning PID gains on joints doesn't cause the robot to collapse or Gazebo to error due to high effort/velocity values.  When can we get this into the Debian repository version so that all my VRC team can start tuning controllers?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-02-14**:
will create a new pr targeted at gazebo_1.4 for patch release.